# Python3 Multiprocessing os.fork operates on the same resource?

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing, ram

```
import os
a=[]
pid=os.fork()
if(pid!=0):
    a.append(1)
    print("Original: ", end='')
    print(a,id(a))
else:
    a.append(2)
    print("Child: ", end='')
    print(a,id(a))

# Result:
# Original: [1] 139725666412296
# Child: [2] 139725666412296
```

1. Why the parent and the child process share the same resource id?
2. If they share the same id, after I appended 2 to the list, why child process didn't print out 2?

3.
I then printed out (in a new Jupyter notebook code block) what lst contains now after executing the above code block. It prints: [1]. If the parent process executes first and child process executes last, why lst isn't [1,2]?

Comment: ID distinctness guarantees only apply within a single process. Equal IDs in separate processes mean nothing.

Answer (score 1):

*[Partial answer: I address your questions 1 and 2 but not 3.]*

`fork` can be thought of as producing a process that starts with a **copy** of the parent process memory but then the two can be separately modified so the contents can diverge after the initial copy.  In fact for efficiency it is implemented as copy-on-write, so that any copying only takes place if and when memory pages are actually modified, but this fact should not affect the *concept* of it being a copy.

This means that, to answer your questions 1 and 2, the ID of the object is the same because it was created before the fork, but the assignments done after the fork will not be visible in the other process.  In any case, you have no control here over the timings of the execution in the parent and child process (but even if the timing varied, the results of each would not be affected, only possibly the order in which they were collated).